# Decoding base64 string in R gives unexpected binary output

Tags: r, base64, jsonlite

I have this string:

```
x <- "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"
```

I know it has been encoded using base64. Doing a quick search on internet, I found that in R there are some packages to encode/decode base64.

- Package `jsonlite` with the function `base64dec()`
- Package `base64decode` with the function `base64decode()`.

In both cases, when running...

- `base64dec(x)`
- `base64decode(x)`

I get this result, which is a binary output:

```
   [1] 5b 7b 22 63 6f 64 65 22 3a 22 42 31 31 38 32 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 22 3a 22 54 69 72 65 20 70 72 65 73 73 75 72 65 20 6d 6f 6e 69 74 6f 72
  [54] 20 6d 6f 64 75 6c 65 22 2c 22 66 61 75 6c 74 49 6e 66 6f 72 6d 61 74 69 6f 6e 73 22 3a 5b 7b 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 22 3a 22 2d 2d 2d 22 7d 2c 7b
 [107] 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 22 3a 22 54 52 55 45 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 5f 65 6e 67 22 3a 22 54 52 55 45 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69
 [160] 70 74 69 6f 6e 5f 66 72 65 22 3a 22 54 52 55 45 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 5f 67 65 72 22 3a 22 54 52 55 45 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69
 [213] 6f 6e 5f 73 70 61 22 3a 22 54 52 55 45 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 5f 69 74 61 22 3a 22 54 52 55 45 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 5f
 [266] 74 75 72 22 3a 22 54 52 55 45 22 7d 5d 2c 22 66 72 65 65 7a 65 46 72 61 6d 65 73 22 3a 5b 5d 2c 22 65 6e 68 61 6e 63 65 64 44 74 63 49 6e 66 6f 73 22 3a 5b 5d
 [319] 2c 22 73 74 61 74 75 73 22 3a 22 41 43 54 49 56 45 22 2c 22 73 79 73 74 65 6d 22 3a 22 4d 55 4c 54 49 46 55 4e 43 54 49 4f 4e 22 2c 22 73 79 73 74 65 6d 4d 65
 [372] 74 61 22 3a 7b 22 73 79 73 74 65 6d 4e 61 6d 65 22 3a 6e 75 6c 6c 2c 22 73 75 62 53 79 73 74 65 6d 4e 61 6d 65 22 3a 6e 75 6c 6c 7d 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70
 [425] 74 69 6f 6e 5f 65 6e 67 22 3a 22 54 69 72 65 20 70 72 65 73 73 75 72 65 20 6d 6f 6e 69 74 6f 72 20 6d 6f 64 75 6c 65 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e
 [478] 5f 66 72 65 22 3a 22 4d 6f 64 75 6c 65 20 64 65 20 73 75 72 76 65 69 6c 6c 61 6e 63 65 20 64 65 20 6c 61 20 70 72 65 73 73 69 6f 6e 20 64 65 73 20 70 6e 65 75
 [531] 73 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 5f 67 65 72 22 3a 22 52 65 69 66 65 6e 64 72 75 63 6b c3 bc 62 65 72 77 61 63 68 75 6e 67 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72
 [584] 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 5f 73 70 61 22 3a 22 4d c3 b3 64 75 6c 6f 20 64 65 20 63 6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 20 64 65 20 6c 61 20 70 72 65 73 69 c3 b3 6e 20 64 65 20 6c 6f 73
 [637] 20 6e 65 75 6d c3 a1 74 69 63 6f 73 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 5f 69 74 61 22 3a 22 4d 6f 64 75 6c 6f 20 6d 6f 6e 69 74 6f 72 20 64 69 20 70 72
 [690] 65 73 73 69 6f 6e 65 20 70 6e 65 75 6d 61 74 69 63 6f 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 5f 74 75 72 22 3a 22 4c 61 73 74 69 6b 20 62 61 73 c4 b1 6e 63
 [743] c4 b1 20 69 7a 6c 65 6d 65 20 6d 6f 64 c3 bc 6c c3 bc 22 7d 2c 7b 22 63 6f 64 65 22 3a 22 42 31 32 34 44 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 22 3a 22 53
 [796] 65 6e 73 6f 72 2c 20 74 79 72 65 20 70 72 65 73 73 75 72 65 22 2c 22 66 61 75 6c 74 49 6e 66 6f 72 6d 61 74 69 6f 6e 73 22 3a 5b 7b 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74
 [849] 69 6f 6e 22 3a 22 2d 2d 2d 22 7d 2c 7b 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 22 3a 22 54 52 55 45 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 5f 65 6e 67 22 3a 22
 [902] 54 52 55 45 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 5f 66 72 65 22 3a 22 54 52 55 45 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 5f 67 65 72 22 3a 22 54 52 55
 [955] 45 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 5f 73 70 61 22 3a 22 54 52 55 45 22 2c 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 5f 69 74 61 22 3a
```

However, when I copy that string into [this web](https://www.base64decode.org/), I get this result:

```
[{"code":"B1182","description":"Tire pressure monitor module","faultInformations":[{"description":"---"},{"description":"TRUE","description_eng":"TRUE","description_fre":"TRUE","description_ger":"TRUE","description_spa":"TRUE","description_ita":"TRUE","description_tur":"TRUE"}],"freezeFrames":[],"enhancedDtcInfos":[],"status":"ACTIVE","system":"MULTIFUNCTION","systemMeta":{"systemName":null,"subSystemName":null},"description_eng":"Tire pressure monitor module","description_fre":"Module de surveillance de la pression des pneus","description_ger":"Reifendrucküberwachung","description_spa":"Módulo de control de la presión de los neumáticos","description_ita":"Modulo monitor di pressione pneumatico","description_tur":"Lastik basıncı izleme modülü"},{"code":"B124D","description":"Sensor, tyre pressure","faultInformations":[{"description":"---"},{"description":"TRUE","description_eng":"TRUE","description_fre":"TRUE","description_ger":"TRUE","description_spa":"TRUE","description_ita":"TRUE","description_tur":"TRUE"}],"freezeFrames":[],"enhancedDtcInfos":[],"status":"ACTIVE","system":"MULTIFUNCTION","systemMeta":{"systemName":null,"subSystemName":null},"description_eng":"Sensor, tyre pressure","description_fre":"Capteur, pression des pneus","description_ger":"Sensor Reifendruck","description_spa":"Sensor de presión del neumático","description_ita":"Sensore, pressione pneumatici","description_tur":"Sensör, lastik hava basıncı"}]
```

This is actually the expected output. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the output is raw encoded. So you'll need to use `rawToChar`.

```
library(base64)
rawToChar(base64_decode(x))
[1] "[{\"code\":\"B1182\",\"description\":\"Tire pressure monitor module\",\"faultInformations\":[{\"description\":\"---\"},{\"description\":\"TRUE\",\"description_eng\":\"TRUE\",\"description_fre\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ger\":\"TRUE\",\"description_spa\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ita\":\"TRUE\",\"description_tur\":\"TRUE\"}],\"freezeFrames\":[],\"enhancedDtcInfos\":[],\"status\":\"ACTIVE\",\"system\":\"MULTIFUNCTION\",\"systemMeta\":{\"systemName\":null,\"subSystemName\":null},\"description_eng\":\"Tire pressure monitor module\",\"description_fre\":\"Module de surveillance de la pression des pneus\",\"description_ger\":\"Reifendrucküberwachung\",\"description_spa\":\"Módulo de control de la presión de los neumáticos\",\"description_ita\":\"Modulo monitor di pressione pneumatico\",\"description_tur\":\"Lastik basıncı izleme modülü\"},{\"code\":\"B124D\",\"description\":\"Sensor, tyre pressure\",\"faultInformations\":[{\"description\":\"---\"},{\"description\":\"TRUE\",\"description_eng\":\"TRUE\",\"description_fre\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ger\":\"TRUE\",\"description_spa\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ita\":\"TRUE\",\"description_tur\":\"TRUE\"}],\"freezeFrames\":[],\"enhancedDtcInfos\":[],\"status\":\"ACTIVE\",\"system\":\"MULTIFUNCTION\",\"systemMeta\":{\"systemName\":null,\"subSystemName\":null},\"description_eng\":\"Sensor, tyre pressure\",\"description_fre\":\"Capteur, pression des pneus\",\"description_ger\":\"Sensor Reifendruck\",\"description_spa\":\"Sensor de presión del neumático\",\"description_ita\":\"Sensore, pressione pneumatici\",\"description_tur\":\"Sensör, lastik hava basıncı\"}]"
```

**Edit**

To better understand why this is necessary we can check the class of the output of `base64_decode()`.

```
> class(base64_decode(x))
#[1] "raw"
```

The `?raw` helpfully tells us:

> The raw type is intended to hold raw bytes. It is possible to extract subsequences of bytes, and to replace elements (but only by elements of a raw vector). ... A raw vector is printed with each byte separately represented as a pair of hex digits. If you want to see a character representation (with escape sequences for non-printing characters) use rawToChar.

So we just need to convert the raw bytes to character.

Data

```
x <- "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"
```

Comment: Nice! Could you explain a little bit further the rawToChar function?

Comment: Awesome and perfectly explained!